# Trying to post directly to an application's wall

Tags: facebook, oauth, facebook-wall

I'm trying to post directly to an application's wall without linking it to my account. I keep getting a "(OAuthException) (#200) The user has not granted the application the permission to automatically publish feed stories". This is from a winform application.

```
        var oAuthClient = new FacebookOAuthClient();
        oAuthClient.AppId = "APP_ID";
        oAuthClient.AppSecret = "APP_SECRET";
        dynamic token = oAuthClient.GetApplicationAccessToken();

        var appToken = token.access_token;

        FacebookClient fbClient = new FacebookClient(appToken.ToString());
        var args = new Dictionary<string, object>();
        args["message"] = "Testing 123456789 from C#";
        fbClient.Post("/APP_ID/feed", args);
```

Answer (score 1):

Citing from facebook docs for stream.publish:

> Posting to Your Application's Profile Page
>
> In order to use stream.publish to post on the Wall of your application profile page (your application's About Page), all the following conditions must be true:
>
> - The posting user needs to grant the application the publish_stream extended permission.
> - The posting user must like the application's profile page.
> - A developer of the application must edit the application profile page's Wall Settings (Edit Application > Edit) and verify under Posting Ability that Fans can write or post content on the wall is checked.

From this it is obvious you cannot post to application wall with application token, only with token of user that likes the app.

Comment: And a user token can only be generated through https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=YOUR_APP_ID&redirect_uri=YOUR_URL&response_type=token ? I was hoping to keep the user from having to enter his/her login/password for every wall post.

Comment: A user token is obtainable any time user is logged-in (at the client-side) and can be used in server-side as well, but expires after a time (look facebook docs on authentication, server-side flow). You can have non-expiring ones, but user must grant you offline_access privilege (Bad Thing). It is by design that apps cannot write to their app wall (apps only write where user that authorized them can write). But yes, you can only get user token by user action, that's what it is about.