# Post Directly To the app's wall

Tags: iphone, ios, facebook

i'm trying to post directly from my iOS App to the Facebook application page but with no luck.

i have read this 
[iOS post to the Facebook app wall](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7495472/ios-post-to-the-facebook-app-wall)
and this
[Trying to post directly to an application's wall](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8173699/trying-to-post-directly-to-an-applications-wall)

but no luck with that.

help please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
-(void)postToFacebookAppPage
{
    NSMutableDictionary* params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                   @"##########...", @"app_id",
                                   @"##########...",@"to",

                                   //@"http://www.facebook.com/pages/AppPageURL", @"link",
                                   //@"icon.png", @"picture",
                                   //@"App Page Name", @"name",
                                   //@"Post to App Facebook Page", @"caption",
                                   @"Do Stuff Facebook page.", @"description",
                                   nil];



    AppDelegate *sharedAppDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    [sharedAppDelegate.facebook dialog:@"feed" andParams:params andDelegate:self]; 
}
```

Where the numbers #### are for your page.

Comment: thanks for the quick respond , in the "to" field do you meen the link the the page ?

Comment: Yes, to is your app's page, your app_id is the app that will be posting it (This assumes your app has a fan page, aka, a business page, which I believe is required now).

Comment: ok thanks , for now its not working but i'm guessing this is because i havent published the page yet

Comment: not sure what to tell you, it works in my application, make sure your shared App Delegate is sep up correctly.

Comment: instead of posting to feed, you need to use page_id/feed. i.e [sharedAppDelegate.facebook dialog:@"pageid/feed" andParams:params andDelegate:self];

Answer (score 1):

```
-(void)postToFacebookAppPage
{
    NSMutableDictionary* params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                   @"##########...", @"app_id",


                                   //@"http://www.facebook.com/pages/AppPageURL", @"link",
                                   //@"icon.png", @"picture",
                                   //@"App Page Name", @"name",
                                   //@"Post to App Facebook Page", @"caption",
                                   @"Do Stuff Facebook page.", @"description",
                                   nil];



    AppDelegate *sharedAppDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    [sharedAppDelegate.facebook dialog:@"pageid/feed" andParams:params andDelegate:self]; 
}
```