# How to post on Facebook wall through an iOS app?

Tags: ios, xcode4, fbconnect

In my application i try to integrate New FBconnect api using this tutorial ,but when i run this tutorial source code its give me following Errors[image].

Here is link of this Tutorial http://gabriel-tips.blogspot.com/2011/10/how-to-post-on-facebook-wall-through.html.

I request to all Who want to help me please check this tutorial before Answering me,bcz my work is related as done in this tutorial.so please guide me about this tutorial.Any help will be appriated.Thanx in advance.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10390035/post-directly-to-the-apps-wall/10390335#10390335 similar

Comment: I had downloaded code but It is not giving any error..

Comment: Please @Mehul can u share the steps after downloaded what changes u make.?thanx

Comment: Had not done any changes, open it in XCode 4.2 and build it..and It build succeed

Comment: But @Mehul I have XCode 4.1 .

Comment: @Mehul You should both update to 4.3.3, the most recent non-beta Xcode version.

Answer (score 1):

Forget about older tutorials and random sample code found on the web. Facebook has an official sample project for you to use called [HackBook](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk/tree/master/sample/Hackbook). It includes several working examples that you can dissect. You should download this, read their instructions, and see exactly how to achieve Facebook functionality within your app.

Answer (score 0):

There is a api called AddThis. You can use that api to share anything over hundreds of social networking sites including twitter and Facebook.
You will get the documents and api on this link.

http://www.addthis.com/